# Server architecture puzzle, C programming

Tags: c, multithreading, architecture, locking, pthreads

In my program, I use a single thread pool to dispatch all my task, like timer task, non-blocking socket I/O, etc. A task is actually an callback function, which will be executed when specific event received.

The architecture is :

1. The main thread calls epoll() to harvest the I/O event, then dispatch the I/O callback to the thread pool.
2. The main thread also handle timer timeout, and dispatch the timeout callback to the thread pool
3. In an I/O callback, one timer task may be cancelled, depending on I/O processing result.
4. During one I/O callback is running, the coresponding socket is not monitored for further identical event.
5. Durning one timer callback is running, that timer task will temporarily removed from the timer task queue.

Here is the problem:

1. During thread A in the pool is running a timer callback T.
2. Thread B in the pool may be running another callback(registered for an socket I/O read event), after processing request received, thread B decide to delete the timer task T, but that timer task T is being executed by thread A right now.

I can add an lock for the timer task, but where should I place the lock? I can't place the lock object in the timer task structure, because when I decide to free the task object, I must have already acquired the lock, free and held lock, may lead to undefined behaviours:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(T->mutex);
 free(T);
 /*without a pthread_mutex_unlock(T->mutex);*/
```

And what happened if another thread is blocked on :

```
pthread_mutex_lock(T->mutex);
```

Without these problem being addressed, I can't continue my work.Please HELP me out!

Should I use separate thread pool for task of different types in my single process? Or just use single thread?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: How does thread B know that there is a timer callback T? Whatever structure it uses to find that out should have a lock and should also track the status of the timer callback if there is one.

Comment: I don't understand why "free and held lock, may lead to undefined behaviours."?if you don't think your code can handle these things okay,maybe the libevent is what you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The I/O callback being executed by thread B and the timer callback being executed by thread A, are registered together, by the same functions. This program process client requests, and keep a timer for each client. If no data received before timer expired, the client connection will be destroyed. Thank you .

Comment: @KerrekSB I decide to implement my timer in application layer in the early stage. I don't know how many timers one timerfd can handle, I will read the manual, maybe it's an option. thank you.

Comment: @cheneydeng I use pthread_mutex_t as an lock. If I want to destroy timer T in one thread, the code may like this: `pthread_mutex_lock(T->mutex); free(T); /*Without a pthread_mutex_unlock(T->lock);*/`. And I don't know what happened if another thread is doing `pthread_mutex_lock(T->mutex);`

Comment: @cheneydeng Thank you. I don't know how to use libevent in conjunction with thread pool. What I think libevent just provides an event interface, but how to dispatch the event is the programmer's work. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global table of timers protected by its own mutex. The table does not actually need to be global but can belong to some collection, such as whatever owns all the things you are doing I/O on.

Then use this logic:

**To create a timer**:

1. Lock the global table.
2. Add the timer to the global table in state "pending".
3. Unlock the global table.
4. Schedule the timer with the thread pool.

**To fire a timer**:

1. Lock the global table.
2. Check the timer's state. If it's not "pending", delete the timer, unlock the table, and stop.
3. Change the timer's state to "firing".
4. Unlock the global table.
5. Perform the timer operation.
6. Lock the global table.
7. Remove the timer from the table.
8. Unlock the global table.

**To cancel a timer**:

1. Lock the global table.
2. Find the timer. If it's state is "pending", change it to "cancelled". Do not delete it.
3. Unlock the global table.

Comment: Thank you very much, David. So this solutions is that only do the cancel operation in the dispatcher thread, worker thread just mark the timer is "to be cancelled". There may be a case : worker A is running timer task T, worker B mark it as "cancelled", but to let dispatcher thread know when timer T finished execution, I have to add another flag to indicate whether the task is still running. Do I understand well?

Comment: @longbowk: You got it. If you go to cancel the timer and it's not in the table, then you know it either wasn't set or fired already. If it's "pending" and you change it to "cancelled", then you know you cancelled it successfully. If it's "firing", then you know that you are too late to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you refernce count the tasks? When thread A in the pool is running a timer callback T you mark it (e.g. using interlocked increment). When it finishes you decrement the usage. It cannot be freed until the usage is zero.

Comment: @lvoTops thanks. I have thought about this solution. But this lead to another problem: worker thread A unref the timer T(cancel the timer), and find the count==0, it decide to free the timer T. But at very same time,  worker thread B is going to reference the timer for execution, ref(T). Then thread B must check whether the count is zero, before reference it. So does it need a lock to make the test_nozero() and ref()  operation as an atomic operation?

Comment: Just create a single fast lock for all timer add/get operations.  That way nobody can get/ref a new lock when one is being freed.